# How to get the Department field from the Office profile using Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365

I'm trying to get the Department field from the Contact Information in the Office 365 profile using the Microsoft Graph API, but the data being returned doesn't match.

[Screenshot of contact information in office.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbXyr.png)
[Screenshot of the query in the Graph Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Auqf6.png)

**Example**:
Office 365 user profile page: `https://nam.delve.office.com/?u=d10110c2-5f89-40dc-8db2-323e35e24f73&v=editprofile`
Microsoft Graph API query: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/department`
Microsoft Graph API query result:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('d10110c2-5f89-40dc-8db2-323e35e24f73')/department",
    "value": "Clinical"
}
```

I logged into `office.com`  and the Microsoft Graph Explorer using the same account, and all fields seems to match, except this particular field which doesn't.

Could anyone help me find out what am I missing there?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to repro this behavior. For me, a response from graph API matches the department name stated on the profile page(office.com)

Couple of things to check here -

1. Make sure you are logged in with correct account at both places.
2. If not, please share actual screen shot from both places. Also please share request timestamp and client id from graph call.

Hope this helps. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with a bit more of data that can help demonstrate the issue. How can I show the timestamps in the Graph Explorer requests?